# Getting data between 3 tables correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working towards linking data from Table1 to Table3. I am using Microsoft SQL Server. I am not too experienced but off of my research and testing, I should be using Joins I believe. 
I am trying to get all of Table3's columns based off of Table 1's name. This path should be name to name, statecode to statecode. How could I go along of getting this to work? I have also supplied my attempted code.

Written example of the senario: "Lets say there are 40 rows in table3. 10 of those rows have a state code of 220. Bob lives in state code 220. It should then display the 10 rows in table3 of the statecode of 220 since the name is 'Bob'."

Table1 columns

```
name | email | phone
```

Table2 columns

```
name | statecode | company
```

Table3 columns

```
amount | statecode | average
```

Attempted Code

```
select table3.* 
from table3
inner join table2
on table3.statecode = table2.statecode
inner join table1
on table2.name = table1.name
where table1.name = 'Bob'
```

Comment: someone should maybe suggest a better design, perhaps highlighting linking on id's rather than what the sample is showing, seeing as the OP states that he's not too experienced. See this for reference: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341391/answering-a-question-with-a-different-approach-altogether

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention SQL Server I've adopted TSQL styling, I've assumed that the tables are related by the columns with common names, this needn't be the case but seems likely. With a more traditional schema I'd expect some or all tables to have an `Id` column that would act as the key for that table. Then foreign keys might be named `TableId`. The keys would have a simple type, perhaps `Int32` to enable swift indexing and constraints.

```
SELECT
            C.[Amount],
            C.[StateCode],
            C.[Average]
    FROM
            [Table1] A
       JOIN
            [Table2] B
                ON A.[Name] = B.[Name]
       JOIN
            [Table3] C
                ON B.[StateCode] = C.[StateCode]
    WHERE
            A.[Name] = N'Bob';
```

I've omitted optional keywords, who needs them? I've include quoted identifiers, e.g. `[]`, these are optional but good practice. The case used matches that used extensively on MSDN and the use of whitespace is unusual and optional but I think it aids readability.

Comment: How could this be adjusted so that if there are multiple 'Bob's in  table1, it will only do 1 Bob? This will prevent multiple rows from table3 being the same.

Comment: @Brad, if there are multiple `'Bob'`s in `table1` that would mean `name` is not a candiate key and you should redesign your database a little. When we design a database we are trying to achieve normalistion e.g. 3NF. This is a whole extended topin in itself https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form. For your specific example it would make sense to add an `[Id] IDENTITY` column to `table1` to act as surrogate key. This should act as the foreign key in `table2` e.g. `[Table1Id]`

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with your code?

Here is a (very minor) rewrite, which should work just fine:

```
select t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
from 
table1 t1 
join table2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name
join table3 t3 on t2.statecode = t3.statecode
where t1.name = 'Bob';
```

I've explicity stated that you want to see all the columns, rather than only the data from table3 - and I've provided some table aliases (t1, t2, t3) which I find help structure my work with sql.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to keep in mind the joins using string fields could be too slow when you are working with a huge ammount of records. So, if you could change the structure of the given tables, I would do something like that:

Table1 columns

> IDTable1 (primary key) | name | email | phone

Table2 columns

> IDTable2 (primary key) | FK_IdTable1 (Foreign key to Table1) |
>   statecode | company

Table3 columns

> IDTable3 (primary key) | FK_IdTable2 (Foreign key to Table2) | amount
>   | statecode | average

Then, all you have to do is declare the relations between the tables with a Join.

```
select table3.* 
from table3 t3
     inner join table2 t2
on t3.FK_IdTable2= t2.IDTable2
     inner join table1 t1
on t1.IDTable1 = t2.FK_IdTable1
where t1.name = 'Bob'
```